# Выбранный по умолчанию элемент в кастомном dropdown

Tags: html, jquery, dropdown

Есть кастомный dropdown, не могу сделать так, чтобы при наличии соответствующей записи в cookie, элемент был уже выбран.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" />
  <link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" />
  <title>CodePen - Dropdown Menu</title>



  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css'>

      <style>
      * {
  outline: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
body {
  background-color: #fafafa
}
span.msg,
span.choose {
  color: #555;
  padding: 5px 0 10px;
  display: inherit
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  text-align: center
}

/*Styling Selectbox*/
.dropdown {
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(204, 204, 204);
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #474747;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left
}
.dropdown .select {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px
}
.dropdown .select > i {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    float: right;
    line-height: 20px
}
.dropdown:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(204, 204, 204)
}
.dropdown:active {
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}
.dropdown.active:hover,
.dropdown.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}
.dropdown.active .select > i {
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 0 1px 5px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    max-height: 144px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 9
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer
} 
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:active {
    background-color: #e2e2e2
}
    </style>

  <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>



  <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>

</head>

<body translate="no" >

  <div class="container">
    <span class="choose">Choose Gender</span>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="select">
          <span>Select Gender</span>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="gender">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li id="male">Male</li>
          <li id="female">Female</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

  <span class="msg"></span>
</div>
    <script src="//static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js"></script>

  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>



    <script >
      /*Dropdown Menu*/
$('.dropdown').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(300);
    });
    $('.dropdown').focusout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(300);
    });
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('span').text($(this).text());
        $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('input').attr('value', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
/*End Dropdown Menu*/


$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
  var input = '<strong>' + $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('input').val() + '</strong>',
      msg = '<span class="msg">Hidden input value: ';
  $('.msg').html(msg + input + '</span>');
});
      //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>    

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно ручками менять span и input

```
$('#phones_dropdown_input').attr('value', point.id);
$('#phones_dropdown_span').text(point.text);
```